# Checkbox list checked values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a checkbox list with 3 items in it. I would like to get all the checked values of checkbox list into a single string. I tried the following code, but it does not give correct results.
Can anyone help me in this.

```
<asp:checkboxlist id="interestedIN" runat="server" repeatlayout="table"
    cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" Font-Size="12px">
  <asp:ListItem id= "social" runat="server"  text=" Sociology" Selected="false" />
  <asp:ListItem id="zoo" runat="server"  text=" Zoology " Selected="false" />
  <asp:ListItem id="math" runat="server"  text=" mathematics " Selected="false" />
</asp:checkboxlist>
```

here is the C# i implemented:

```
foreach (ListItem li in interestedIN.Items)
        {
            if (li.Selected)
            {
                interestIN = interestedIN.SelectedItem.Value + "," + interestIN;
            }
        }
```

Output: If user selects Sociology and Zoology, i would like to have the output as "Sociology, Zoology"
But my above code gives me following result "Sociology, Sociology".

Answer (score 7):

I created a Custom CheckBoxList with a property for this.  It's nice to just have this in a control so you don't have to write the code each time.  The custom control allows you to reference four properties:

- SelectedValuesString – A comma-delimited string of the selected values.
- SelectedValuesAsIntegers – An Integer List of the selected values.
- SelectedValuesAsStrings – A string List of the selected values.
- SelectedItemTextAsStrings – A string list of the text for the selected items.

Here's the SelectedValuesAsString property.

```
public string SelectedValuesString
{
    get
    {
        return String.Join(",",this.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i=>i.Value));
    }
}
```

To see the post on the Custom CheckBoxList Control, see http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/extended-checkboxlist-control/

Answer (score 5):

Hope the below function will help you to get the result

```
for (int i = 0; i < interestedIN.Items.Count; i++)
{
   if (interestedIN.Items[i].Selected)
   {
       values += interestedIN.Items[i].Value + ",";
   }
}

values = values.TrimEnd(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var selectedValues =
    (from item in interestedIN.Items.Cast<ListItem>() where item.Selected select item.Text).ToArray();
var selectedValuesJoined = string.Join(",", selectedValues);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this issue is very old, but I have a solution. Your problem is that you're looking at the selected item of the list control, which may or may not be what you need, depending on the state of the list control at the time this runs. You need to be looking at the item that is currently being iterated on and grab the text value from that.

```
string interestIN = String.Empty;

foreach (ListItem li in interestedIN.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected)
    {
        interestIN += li.Text + ", ";
    }
}
```

My code has an issue where the last item will have a trailing comma, but you can figure out how to strip that out. This will get you 99% there.

Answer (score 1):

Made a slight change to Narnian's excellent answer to use c# extension methods:

```
  public static class ExtendedCheckBoxList
{

    public static string SelectedValuesAsCommaDelimmittedString( this CheckBoxList thatCheckBoxList )
    {

        List<string> selectedValuesAsStrings = thatCheckBoxList.SelectedValuesAsStrings();

        string commaDelimmittedStringOfValues = String.Join( ",", selectedValuesAsStrings );

        return commaDelimmittedStringOfValues;
    }


    public static List<string> SelectedValuesAsStrings( this CheckBoxList thatCheckBoxList )
    {
            List<string> selectedValuesAsStrings = thatCheckBoxList
                                                                .Items
                                                                .Cast<ListItem>()
                                                                .Where( i => i.Selected )
                                                                .Select( i => i.Value )
                                                                .ToList();

            return selectedValuesAsStrings;
    }
}
```

Comment: decided to push you over 1000 today... hahaha!  ^_-

Answer (score -2):

Use the following:

```
Boolean addSeperator = false;

foreach (ListItem li in interestedIN.Items)
{

    if (addSeperator)
    {
        interestIN += ", ";
        addSeperator = false;
    }
    if (li.Selected)
    {
        interestIN += li.Text;
        addSeperator = true;
    }
}
```