# How to get the selected value of checkboxlist by using Request.Form[]

Tags: asp.net

I have used a CheckBoxList which ID is "FavouriteGenres". After submitting the form, another aspx page wants to get the selected values. When I debug the code, the key of the parameters have changed to "FavouriteGenres$1","FavouriteGenres$2" and so on(It represents all my selected item). The question is ***How to get all the selected values rather than get them one by one?***[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some pretty good answers here:

[Checkbox list checked values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513502/checkbox-list-checked-values)

Let me know if you still have a question on this.

Comment: After submitting the form, the selected values are transferred as a string type. So maybe I can only get the parameters by its specific keys in Request.Form[].

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET postbacks, or just responding to a POST?  That will change the result considerably.

Comment: I'm responding the request by POST method and I'd like to get the values in another page.

Comment: Sorry, then my suggestion above will not work at all.  The POST situation will just send a list of controls and their values on to the page receiving the post, and as you see, you are getting just the selected values for the FavouriteGenres field.  I am not sure it makes sense to change your approach to postback to the original page to parse out the results--then you could use code from my link above to get the list.  Is that an option for you?

Comment: Yse, maybe I can construct the selected values and then get them all in another page. I just want to find whether there is a method to construct the parameters of that field in that page.

Comment: Unfortunately, using POST, you are outside of the ASP.NET standard postback process and will not get any special help managing the response.  You are forced to use old school HTML form processing at that point.  Sorry!